# converting for loop to java 8 stream

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I was playing around with Java 8. I had some trouble converting this for loop into Java 8 Stream.

```
for (int y = 0; y < 5; y ++) {
    for (int x = y; x < 10; x += 2) {
        System.out.println(x+y);
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! At this site, we like to help each other, but only after you have tried some things (and told us about them) and done some prior research.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, erdekhayser. Yeah, I did do some research myself before I came here to ask. The outer for loop was easy. IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach() would do. But the inner loop with step size as 2 was what threw me off...

Answer (score 12):

The canonical way of converting nested loops is to use `flatMap` on a stream, e.g.

```
IntStream.range(0, 5).flatMap(i->IntStream.range(i, 10))
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The tricky part on your task is the increment by two as this has no direct equivalent in the stream API. There are two possibilities:

1. Use `IntStream.iterate(y, x->x+2)` to define start value and increment. Then you have to modify the infinite stream by `limit`ing the number of elements: `.limit((11-y)/2)`.

   So the resulting code for your loop would look like:

   ```
   IntStream.range(0, 5)
       .flatMap(y->IntStream.iterate(y, x->x+2).limit((11-y)/2)
       .map(x -> x+y)).forEach(System.out::println);
   ```
2. Use `IntStream.range(0, (11-y)/2)` to create an stream of the desired number of ascending `int`s and modify it with `.map(t->y+t*2)` to have it produce the desired values of your inner `for` loop.

   Then, the resulting code for your loop would look like:

   ```
   IntStream.range(0, 5)
       .flatMap(y->IntStream.range(0, (11-y)/2).map(t->y+t*2).map(x -> x+y))
       .forEach(System.out::println);
   ```

Comment: You could also just take an `IntStream.range(a, b)` and then use a `filter(n -> n % 2 == 0)` to filter out the uneven numbers, thus generating a  `+2` variant.

Answer (score 7):

As [Holger pointed out here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23696487/2057294) already, it is certainly doable. The question though is: Why?
I am suspecting an XY problem, streams are not the solution to everything, that is an important fact to remember.

Take a look at what your code is doing, and create a method that does what you want to do, with as much variability as possible, you are:

- Having an `y` maximum (considering you always start at 0)
- Having an `x` maximum (considering you always start at 0)
- Having an `y` increment operation. (Assuming the +1 is not fixed)
- Having an `x` increment operation.
- Then an operation with the `x` and `y`.
- Then you consume the result of the operation.

Hence I propose the following, variability may be reduced if this is not exactly what you want, in other words: You can hardcore more if neccessary.

```
private void doMyDoubleLoop(
        final int yEnd, final IntUnaryOperator yIncrementOperator, 
        final int xEnd, final IntUnaryOperator xIncrementOperator,
        final IntBinaryOperator combiner, final IntConsumer consumer
) {
    for (int y = 0; y < yEnd; y = yIncrementOperator.applyAsInt(y)) {
        for (int x = y; x < xEnd; x = xIncrementOperator.applyAsInt(x)) {
            consumer.accept(combiner.applyAsInt(x, y));
        }
    }
}
```

Used as:

```
doMyDoubleLoop(5, y -> y + 1, 10, x -> x + 2, (x, y) -> x + y, System.out::println);
```

As I said, this might be overkill, so assuming everything revolving around the for-loops is fixed, it suddenly is a lot nicer:

```
private void doMyInternalDoubleLoop(final IntBinaryOperator combiner, final IntConsumer consumer) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        for (int x = y; x < 10; x += 2) {
            consumer.accept(combiner.applyAsInt(x, y));
        }
    }
}
```

Used as:

```
doMyInternalDoubleLoop((x, y) -> x + y, System.out::println);
```

This is a pattern that I would suggest to use if you have a class on which you have operations that use this double-loop a lot, but do not want to copy around the loop, as it should be with DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.

Comment: The point is that streams can be easily parallelized; a `for`-loop: no. Maybe here on this simple example, this might be fine. However, once we deal with much larger datasets, don't get fooled into believing you can use `for`-loops just because it looks simpler. Another useful fact about streams is that they not always require a huge amount of memory to operate.

Comment: @JoD. As long as "streams-as-if-they-were-loops" are going to be so hard to code, then it's from a maintenance point of view better to avoid them and use regular loops as I have pointed out. Don't make things more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: If you have a 10 hr job running, and you know that you have a shot in slashing that down to an hour, then are you going to stick with the loops? Remember that many people simplify their examples for posting their questions. I don't think anyone will use streams to build a 5x6 matrix with input fields - I mean I hope not for the same reasons you mention.

Answer (score 4):

The way I would do this is to use a `filter` on the inner `IntStream`:

```
IntStream
.range(0, 5)
.flatMap(
        y ->
        IntStream
        .range(y, 10)
        .filter(x -> (x-y) % 2 == 0)
        .map(x -> x+y))
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

I've been using this pattern for segmenting data: E.g.

```
IntStream
.range(first, last)
.filter(index -> (index-first) % segment == 0)
.forEach(
        System.out.printf(
                "Doing segment %s to %s%n", 
                index, 
                Math.min(index+seg-1, last)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still trying to figure this out myself.  The following gets no points for style:

```
IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach(y -> 
//<kludge> 
//I would appreciate it if someone would replace this with something smarter.
    IntStream.iterate(y, x -> x + 2)
        .limit(100)
        .filter(x -> x < 10)
//</kludge>
        .forEach( x -> System.out.println(y+x)));
```

The `x += 2` is the tricky part, which would have been trivial if the range method had an "increment" parameter.  I used `iterate` to do the increments myself, but `iterate` produces an *infinite* stream.  I used `filter` to restrict it to the range I want, and put in an arbitrary `limit` so that it wouldn't just overflow and start spitting out large negative numbers that are < 10.