# How to map a for-loop with nested ifs into Java 8 stream when there is assignment of global variable

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I've been attempting to learn Java 8 .stream() and as part of that to convert this for-loop. I can't come across the proper way to go about it. .map, and .forEach don't seem to help here.

My main issue comes when I'm trying to assign a DateFormat releaseDate to a parsed records.getReleaseDate() object and then compare it to a set beforeDate object. Any thoughts?

```
DateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
Date releaseDate = new Date();
Date beforeDate;

beforeDate = sourceFormat.parse("2001.01.01");

Records records = (Records) obj;

for (Record recs : records.getRecordsList()) {
    try {
        releaseDate = sourceFormat.parse(((Record) recs).getReleaseDate());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.err.println("PARSE EXCEPTION. Unable to parse record.getReleaseDate()");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (((Record) recs).getTrackListing().size() > 10) {
        if (releaseDate.before(beforeDate)) {
            Release release = new Release();
            release.setName(((Record) recs).getName());
            release.setTrackCount(((Record) recs).getTrackListing().size());
            data.add(release);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my initial approach to .stream():

```
records.getRecordsList().stream()       
    .filter(r->r.getTrackListing().size()>10)
    .filter(r >sourceFormat.parse(r.getReleaseDate()).before(beforeDate)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: You have shown what you have tried so far, but haven't told us what the problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting for loop to java 8 stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688967/converting-for-loop-to-java-8-stream)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your question, that you don't know how to use the `.map` or `.forEach` streaming functions. `.map` is used to keep the "stream" alive and map the actual objects/values going through the streams (in your case from instances of `Record` to instances of `Release`). `.forEach` is a sink, so that the stream always ends at an `forEach`. Thus, you want to use `.map` (see http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/).

Your source code already has some problems:

1. What if `releaseDate` is parsed and an exception is thrown? The value of `releaseDate` will not change (and may be `new Date()` or the value of the previous record.
2. Why even parsing the `releaseDate` if it's only used if the `getTrackListing().size() > 10`? I'd parse it only after the condition was checked `true`.
3. To use lambdas your "outer variables" must be `final` to be used within the stream.

That said, to get your things working you are on the right track, but you still have to `map` your `recs` to an `release`:

```
// see 3.
final Date beforeDate = sourceFormat.parse("2001.01.01");

records.getRecordsList().stream()       
    .filter(r -> r.getTrackListing().size() > 10)
    .filter(r - {
       // if the parsedDate is invalid we don't want to process, see 1. and 2.
       Date parsedDate;
       try {
          parsedDate = sourceFormat.parse(r.getReleaseDate());
       } catch (ParseException e) {
          System.err.println("...");
          e.printStackTrace();
          parsedDate = null;
       }

       return parsedDate != null && parsedDate.before(beforeDate);
    })
    .map(r -> {
       // map the records to an release
       Release release = new Release();
       release.setName(r.getName());
       release.setTrackCount(r.getTrackListing().size());
       return release;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

I just copy and pasted your code (and fixed obvious syntax errors), so have a close look!

Comment: This is exactly what  I pictured in my head with the function inside of the second .filter() method. Thank you for the concise example with verbose explanations. Also, your comments on my logic were spot on, well put!

Comment: Always glad to help, a "mark as solution" would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't really tested the code, I hope the idea is clear. I would do something like this:

```
final DateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
final Date beforeDate = sourceFormat.parse("2001.01.01");

((Records) obj).getRecordsList()
        .stream()
        .filter(rec -> rec.getTrackListing().size() > 10)
        .filter(rec -> {
            try {
                return sourceFormat.parse(rec.getReleaseDate()).before(beforeDate));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                System.err.println("PARSE EXCEPTION. Unable to parse record.getReleaseDate()");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        })
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(rec -> {
            Release release = new Release();
            release.setName(rec.getName());
            release.setTrackCount(rec.getTrackListing().size());
            return release;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And by the way, if you use Java 8 I would recommend you to use [new date/time api](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) to avoid `ParseException` and null checks, this would be a way cleaner.